# Get text after `:` while using keypress event to build Slack-style Emoji in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji

I want to create Slack-style emoji that shows up when you start using `:`

I have created a Stackblitz reproduction -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-uucibv?file=index.tsx

Here's what I did:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import ES from 'emoji-set';

const TextArea = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  const [openEmoji, setOpenEmoji] = React.useState(false);

  const keyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    if (e.key === ':') {
      setOpenEmoji(true);
    } else {
      setOpenEmoji(false);
    }
  };

  const textChanged = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const newText = e.target.value;

    if (openEmoji) {
      console.log(ES.getKeywords(newText));
    }

    setText(newText);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        value={text}
        onKeyDown={keyDown}
        onChange={textChanged}
        placeholder="Type here..."
        spellCheck={false}
        style={{
          width: '350px',
          height: '50vh'
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>React Slack Emoji</h1>
        <TextArea />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I created a simple `textarea` that detects keypresses. I detect when `:` is pressed but I am confused as to how do I get everything after a `:`

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-set

I'm calling `ES.getKeywords` right when I press `:` but I need some way to get everything after keywords. For example, if I write `:c` then I should be returned `ca`, `cabbage`, `cactus` & all other keywords starting from `c`. However, I am unable to get everything after `:` perfectly.

I want the emoji-picker to be fast & performant as well as show the emoji's typed right there.

Currently, I get returned every Emoji when I search `:` as the string is empty.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things have to change. First, your assumption that each key down should control your emoji state is off because `:c` as in your example requires two key presses. The first sets the emoji state, then the second immediately clears it causing a problem. Second, your dependency says that the proper method to call is `searchByKeyword` not `getKeywords`.

In my code I have an assumption that when you are editing an emoji and press space, the emoji processing gets stopped. But basically you have to change from a single key press triggering checking to be a toggle that checks while the `:` condition is met.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import ES from 'emoji-set';

const TextArea = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  const [openEmoji, setOpenEmoji] = React.useState(false);

  const keyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    // changed
    if (e.key === ':' && !openEmoji) {
      setOpenEmoji(true);
    } else if (e.key === ' ' && openEmoji) {
      setOpenEmoji(false);
    } else if (e.key === ':' && openEmoji) {
      setOpenEmoji(false);
    }
  };

  const textChanged = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const newText = e.target.value;
    const emojiToSearch = newText.split(/:/).pop(); // changed
    
    // changed
    if (openEmoji && emojiToSearch && emojiToSearch.length > 1) {
      console.log(ES.searchByKeyword(emojiToSearch));
    }

    setText(newText);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        value={text}
        onKeyDown={keyDown}
        onChange={textChanged}
        placeholder="Type here..."
        spellCheck={false}
        style={{
          width: '350px',
          height: '50vh'
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>React Slack Emoji</h1>
        <TextArea />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Modified stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-uucibv?file=index.tsx)

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. I figured out about the `searchByKeyword` method but the other parts were confusing to me, especially the one about space.

Comment: @deadcoder0904 that is something you could remove if needed, basically you just want to decide when to set the toggle and remove the toggle, but you need to know the state of the toggle already to know whether or not you should toggle it on or off

Comment: I don't think anything else other than space makes sense. Slack does the same thing I guess but I get your point.

Comment: Oh, I tried it again & it doesn't work for `\n`. I guess I need a list of characters other than space to make that check :)